# Doubt in proof of Milman-Pettis Theorem in Brezis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I was reading Proof of Milman-Pettis Theorem. In that I do not understand highlighted text

Why such f exist such that $<\psi,f>>1-\delta/2$ [image]

[image]

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any normed linear space (not equal to $\{0\}$) $\|x\|=\sup \{|f(x)|: \|f\|= 1\}$. In this case  $\sup \{|f(\xi)|: \|f\|= 1\}=1$ and  the result follow by definition of supremum.

An even stronger statement is holds if $\xi \in E$. We can find $f$ such that $\|f\|=1$ and $f(\xi)=1$.  This follows from Banach -Alaoglu Theorem.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this stronger statement follows from Banach-Alaoglu?

Comment: @MaoWao The closed unit ball of $E^{*}$ is compact in weak* topology. We can take $(f_i)$ in the ball such that $f_i(\xi) \to 1$ and then extract a subnet converging to some f$. This $f$ is the one that works.

Comment: No. $\xi$ is from $E^{\ast\ast}$, not from $E$, so weak$^\ast$ convergence is not enough. For $\xi\in E$, this stronger statement follows already from Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @MaoWao You are right. I was thinking of $\xi \in E$ when  I wrote the stronger statement.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the definition of norm:
$$ \|\xi\|_{E^{**}}=1=\sup_{\|f\|_{E^*=1}} \langle \xi,f\rangle_{E^{**},E^*}. $$
Then for each $\frac{\delta}{2}>0$ there exists $\tilde{f}\in E^*, \|f\|_{E^*}=1$ so that
$$ \langle \xi,\tilde{f}\rangle_{E^{**},E^*} \geq 1-\frac{\delta}{2}.
$$